# Consultar valor de variables PHP en sistema con Angular

Tags: php, angular, depuración

DESEO SABER EL VALOR DE $total, $total_op, $banco del lado de PHP ya que la funcion no esta funcionando y no se como debuguearla del lado de php, var_dump, y echo no me sirven por el tema de angular. Cualquier apoyo agradecido, soy novato en angular por eso medio perdido con esto Gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Controlador Angular:

```
ac.saveRecordCuentas= function () {
    ac.savingRequest = true;
    var parameter = JSON.stringify({ session: true, data: ac.edit });
    $http.post(window.location.origin + '/api/?action=save_gastos_cuentas', parameter)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        ac.savingRequest = false;
        if (response.data.status == 'OK') {
          angular.element('#addModalCuentas').modal('hide');
          dt.ajax.reload();
        }
      });
  }
```

CODIGO PHP

```
public function save_gastos_cuentas(){

        $response = $this->response;

        $rdata = $this->data['data'];

            $sql = mysqli_query($this->parent->mysql, "select sum(monto) as total
                                                    from operaciones
                                                    where banco=". $rdata['banco'] ." and (date(fecha) between '".$this->data['fdesde']."' and '".$this->data['fhasta']."');");

            $total = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            $sql = mysqli_query($this->parent->mysql, "select sum(monto) as total
                                                        from operaciones_op
                                                        where banco=". $rdata['banco'] ." and (date(fecha) between '".$this->data['fdesde']."' and '".$this->data['fhasta']."');");
            $total_op = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            $sql = mysqli_query($this->parent->mysql, "select nombre
                                                        from banco
                                                        where id=". $rdata['banco'] .";");

            $banco = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            mysqli_query($this->parent->mysql, "insert into gastos
                (
                    pais,
                    metodo,
                    concepto,
                    monto,
                    fecha,
                    gasto,
                    porc
                ) values (
                    '".$rdata['pais']."',
                    '".$rdata['metodo']."',
                    '".$banco['nombre']."',
                    '".$total['total'] + $total_op['total']."',
                    '".$rdata['fhasta']."',
                    '".($rdata['gasto']*1)."',
                    '".(100*1)."'
                )");

        return $response;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero:

cambia

```
'".$total['total'] + $total_op['total']."',
```

por

```
'".($total['total'] + $total_op['total'])."',
```

y segundo

cambia

```
$this->data['fdesde']
```

por

```
['fdesde']
```

Comment: Es recomendable agregar al menos una breve explicacion de la solucion planteada en tu respuesta